# Are there any Android NDK examples, on how to pass a file from Java to C++ using JNI?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am not sure, if this is the right place to ask, but I am curious, if there are any Android NDK examples (apks), on how to read a file with Java and pass it over to C/ C++ using JNI.

Currently I am trying to read pdf or office files (e.g. docx) with C/ C++ and I am trying to understand the concept behind it.

Maybe there are some full apk examples or just some snippets, with which I could extend the hello-jni/ hello-jnicallback examples.

I already found the android ndk samples site https://github.com/android/ndk-samples, but there seems to be no example on how to simply read files.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can pass a `byte[]` to JNI-land and read it from there...

Comment: Thanks. So I have to convert a file in Java first into a byte[] and then pass it to JNI-Land?
Does this work for all kinds of file formats? Images, Pdfs, Office Documents etc.?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Files are just byte arrays on disk.